# java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: for the second method

Tags: java, android, c++, java-native-interface, unsatisfiedlinkerror

I am trying to invoke a native callback method from an IntentService written in java. The code  snippet in IntentService is like this -

```
private static native void native_notificationCallback();
public void somemethod(){
    //some other code... 
    native_notificationCallback();
}
```

Another one is in a separate class -

```
private static native void native_initCallback();
public void somemethod(){
    //some other code... 
    native_initCallback();
}
```

The inteface.cpp is like this -

```
void JNICALL Notification_initCallback(JNIEnv* env, jobject obj)
{
    //code
}

void JNICALL Notification_notificationCallback(JNIEnv* env, jobject obj)
{
    //code
}

void init(){
    static const JNINativeMethod methods[] =
    {
        {"native_initCallback","()V",(void*)&Notification_initCallback},
        {"native_notificationCallback","()V",(void*)&Notification_notificationCallback}
    };

    // Register the native hooks
    if (env->RegisterNatives(cls, methods,sizeof(methods)/sizeof(methods[0])))
        goto fail;
}
```

The problem is when I call `native_initCallback` it works perfect, but when I call `native_notificationCallback` the app crashes giving `java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError`. I don't understand why it worked for the first method and why not for second, since both of them are almost identical except the name.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You say that the two native methods are in different classes, but in your `RegisterNatives` call you assign them both to one class. If you want to register each method with a different class you'll have to make two `RegisterNatives` calls. The method is keyed by the class, the name and the signature.

Comment: Sheesh!! It was so obvious. Silly me. Thanks a lot. I've wasted half of my sleep on this :-/